# These two single quotes are confusing me

Tags: python, break, continue

```
for char in 'python string':
    if char == '':  # 1: problem
        break
    print(char, end='')  #2: problem
    if char == 'o':
        continue
```

- 1: when I am giving single space between this 2 quotation marks 
  it is showing a result and when no space between is showing another
  result. Why?
- 2: when I give a single space between this 2
  quotation marks words are spacing. why?

Comment: For problem 1:
where you're giving single space then it is matching to one of the character in your string which space between **python string** but when you're not giving space in if block (#1 problem) then it is not matching any character and break is not getting executed and that's the reason for loop execution goes on without any interruption.

Comment: For problem 2:
when we use end param of print() then it prints that as it is along as end character that's the reason why you're giving a space you're observing space.

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

`''` and `' '` are different. The first is an empty string, and the second is a length-1 string with a space in it. The comparison inside your for-loop will never return true, either. Iterating over the string returns each character in it, which are by definition of length 1. So the `char == ''` comparison is always `False`. But if you put a space in there, it will return `True` when `char` is the space in the phrase `'python string'`.

## 2:

The `end` keyword to the `print` function defines what to print after all positional arguments have been printed. It defaults to `'\n'`, to print a newline. So using `print('python', 'string', end=' ')` will print the string `python string`  (note the extra space at the end).

Answer (score 0):

End argument defines what needs to be appended at the end of what is being printed. It defaults to new line character ('\n) or to whatever character is given.

```
for char in 'python string':
    print(char)

p
y
t
h
o
n

s
t
r
i
n
g
```

When no space is given, or an empty string, it prints out what the string is:

```
for char in 'python string':
    print(char, end ='')

python string
```

With a single space, it gets appended to each character:

```
for char in 'python string':
    print(char, end =' ')

p y t h o n   s t r i n g
```

With a double space, then:

```
for char in 'python string':
    print(char, end ='  ')

p  y  t  h  o  n     s  t  r  i  n  g
```